# php threading implementation for a extension

Tags: php, multithreading, native-code

I am developing a Typo3-Extension which uses php to control and execute different shell scripts. The problem is the scripts are running simultaneously and are blocking the page from loading.

How can I implement pthreads, gearmanworker, deamon ... or a fake thread hack without installing it onto the webserver / bypass the problem?

Edit:

- I do need the output
- The php version is 5.4.45

Comment: Do you need the output of those scripts or do you just need to trigger them?

Comment: I do need the output. The momentary execution would be: exec($scriptFilePath . ' 2>&1', $this->output);

Comment: If you use `php-fpm`, you can use [fastcgi_finish_request](http://php.net/fastcgi_finish_request) to return the response to browser and to resume the work in background. But since you need the output.. you can try pthreads extension for PHP.

Comment: I have not looked into the matter but can I include pthreads from my extension-directory?

Comment: You can enable pthreads extension as you do with any other php extension, and you can execute each of your functions in separate thread, wait for all of them to finish and then return the collective output to the browser. [Here's the link to extension repository](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the shell executions are waiting for their return values before the original PHP script continues. If you want to achieve parallel processing you'll have to do something like `nohup myscript.sh > /dev/null 2>&1` (which may be OS dependant). Nohup will make the command continue without the parent process and then you're piping STDERR to STDOUT then both to /dev/null. If you want to capture this into a log file then just change that to wherever you want.

Hope that helps!